# Breaking a list into smaller lists of duplicate elements with the original order preserved (Python)

Tags: python, list

For eg. I have the following list:
    `N=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]`
I need it to be broken down as follows:
    `N2=[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1]]`
where the last '1' remains at its original position **without** being grouped with the other '1's. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always group them manually by iterating over your list, remembering the last element and starting a new list whenever the current element differs from the last one:

```
N = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]

last = object()
data = []
for i in N:
    if i != last:
        data.append([])
    data[-1].append(i)
    last = i

print(data)  # [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`itertools.groupby`**

```
x = [list(i) for _, i in itertools.groupby(N)]

# Result 

[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1]]
```